# How to merge applications to prepare for macOS App Store

Tags: macos, app-store

I am looking for some advice how to optimize the structure of my application in order to prepare it for the macOS app store. My application is a collection of 3 executables, which all rely on a directory called `core`. This directory contains all custom or 3rd party libraries.

```
./Photo Editor/
+----Photo Editor.app (~20MB)
+----Server.app       (~20MB)
+----Client.app       (~20MB)
+----core             (~600MB)
```

Since I can't keep this structure, I have to somehow merge them, correct?

**Merging Idea 1**

Xcode solved a similar issue by moving it into the /Applications directory of the package. But these applications are all independent to each other. In my case, Server.app and Client.app depend on `core`, what would you suggest here?

[image]
**Merging Idea 2**

I make only one application bundle but from a menu I can start itself with a parameter to decide if its a client or server

Do you have another idea, or which one would make more sense? Thanks a lot for any input!